# how to test respond_with_content_type when it's deprecated in shoulda_matches 2.0

Tags: rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails

`respond_with_content_type` matcher is now deprecated in [shoulda-matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers) gem (version > 2.0 and lot of ugly warnings in version 1.5.6)

Thoughtbot suggest that developers should use Integration tests, however this is not always on low resources projects

So question is how to fix broken specs ?  ... or how to replace them

Referring to:

- https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/issues/186
- https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/issues/252
- [Thoughtbots article related to these deprecations](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/47031676783/shoulda-matchers-2-0)

Answer (score 1):

simplest way is to just replace any occurrence of `respond_with_content_type` with :

```
# spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb
describe UsersController do
  before{ get :index, :format => :xlsx }
  it 'response should be excel format' do
    response.content_type.to_s.should eq Mime::Type.lookup_by_extension(:xlsx).to_s
  end
end
```

if you want a proper matcher than:

```
# spec/support/matchers/respond_with_content_type_matchers.rb
RSpec::Matchers.define :respond_with_content_type do |ability|
  match do |controller|
    expected.each do |format|  # for some reason formats are in array
      controller.response.content_type.to_s.should eq Mime::Type.lookup_by_extension(format.to_sym).to_s
    end
  end

  failure_message_for_should do |actual|
    "expected response with content type #{actual.to_sym}"
  end

  failure_message_for_should_not do |actual|
    "expected response not to be with content type #{actual.to_sym}"
  end
end

# spec/spec_helper.rb
...
#ensure support dir is loaded
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}  
...
```

B.T.W.: if you miss matcher `should assign_to` than there is an existing solution https://github.com/tinfoil/shoulda-kept-assign-to . Gem is just a simple shoulda-matcher extension module

Comment: https://github.com/equivalent/scrapbook2/blob/master/archive/blogs/shoulda_matchers_deprecated_what_now.md